# Error starting django web application in cpanel using application manager

Tags: django, deployment, cpanel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXWxZ.png)
***emphasized text***

I am facing an error while deploying my django application on server using application manager in cpanel. image is being attached to it.

Comment: Please post code instead of images of code and errors too, see how do I ask a good question [ask].

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.